# Unable to fix Modernizr: Can't resolve 'generate' error in Webpacker Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

First, `yarn add modernizr modernizr-loader json-loader`.

Then, create `config/webpack/loaders/modernizr-config.json` with,

```
{

  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": []
}
```

Then, create `config/webpack/loaders/modernizr.js` with,

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /modernizr-config\.json$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'modernizr-loader',
            options: require('./modernizr-config.json'),
          },
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.json' ],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, '/modernizr-config.json')
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, import the above file in `config/webpack/environment.js` as

```
const modernizr = require('./loaders/modernizr')

environment.config.merge(modernizr)
```

After importing the modernizr from node_modules,

```
import * as Modernizr from '../../../../../node_modules/modernizr';
```

and running `./bin/webpack`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'generate' in '/private/var/www/project/node_modules/modernizr/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js 151:2-72
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/cli.js
 @ ./app/assets/javascripts/packs/application.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lib/generate-banner' in '/private/var/www/project/node_modules/modernizr/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js 151:2-72
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/cli.js
 @ ./app/assets/javascripts/packs/application.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'package' in '/private/var/www/project/node_modules/modernizr/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js 151:2-72
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/cli.js
 @ ./app/assets/javascripts/packs/application.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #!/usr/bin/env node
| /**
|  * @license r.js 2.1.22 Copyright (c) 2010-2015, The Dojo Foundation All Rights Reserved.
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js 133:18-38
 @ ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/cli.js
 @ ./app/assets/javascripts/packs/application.ts
```